# sudo useradd wont make home directory

Tags: users, sql, useradd

I have an automatic script which works, only it just never makes a home directory. The data is extracted from a database.

Heres the script:

```
 $SQL -s -e "SELECT uid, password FROM registrations WHERE processed = 0"   \
    |  while read A B; do
            sudo useradd   $A -p $B -m
```

as you can see the `-m` is there, but it seems to ignore it and never make a home directory and I have no idea why. I must be missing something but i've no idea what

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it will ignore it, `useradd` needs the login name at the end and the options at the start:

```
useradd [options] LOGIN
```

so it should looks like:

```
sudo useradd -p $B -m $A
```